# Simulating a webcam stream

Tags: windows, video, streaming, directshow, ms-media-foundation

Is it possible to simulate a web-cam output so that other programs that use web-cams (for example Skype) will recognize it as a real web-cam?

Comment: Watch out for upcoming problems. Seen the movie Speed? ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Capture Source Filter download at http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads.htm does exactly that. It uses DirectShow.

Comment: Quite confusing (and does not compile). Is there a good starter guide for DirectShow so I can understand what is going on there? 
Wikipedia says DirectShow is outdated and was replaced by media foundation, is it correct?

Comment: DirectShow is still very much in use, media foundation is to be the successor, but that's still going to be a while. A good place for DirectShow advice is the MSDN forum: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/windowsdirectshowdevelopment/threads/. As for your compilation issues, it is probably related to your environmental setup (include paths, etc). Also, what VS IDE are you using? DirectShow might have a steep learning curve, but once you get into it, it's not that bad. As for the sample, there's prob a lot of COM glue code (haven't seen it in a while).

Comment: P.S. The MSDN docs are quite extensive and would provide you with a good overview of the DirectShow framework: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd375454(v=vs.85).aspx Also, if you're the type that learns by example, the SDK comes with a set of samples that highlight different aspects of DS. More info at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms783352(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 3):

I am the author of that sample : http://tmhare.mvps.org/downloads.htm 
I wrote an actual webcam simulator from that code, so you can do whats needed.

What issues do you have with compilation?

Comment: The OP posted on the MSDN DS forum for compilation help: it was related to setting up the DS env :) No problems with your filter. BTW: nice piece of work!

Comment: Thank you. As Ralf said, the problem was that I did not know that Microsoft SDK ships separately from Visual Studio. After installing it and compiling DS solution, your example compiled and worked as expected.